# Animated hover and active class issue - jQuery

Tags: jquery, tabs, hover, jquery-animate

I'm rather new to jQuery, so I really don't know if the following problem is caused by something very trivial that I don't see. In any case, I searched long and hard for an answer but have found none. I hope you can help me!

I've been trying to code a simple tabbed menu, complementing my sliding content. I wanted the tabs to have some background that will fade in on hover and that the active class is removed and added accordingly to what tab you click.

Here is my code for the fade effect, using the jQuery color plugin:

```
$('#menu a').not('.active').hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#FCEA77', 'opacity': '0.3'}, 'slow');
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#000000', color:'#ffffff', 'opacity': '1'}, 'slow');
});
```

Here is the code for the active class:

```
$('a').click(function () {  
$(".active").removeClass("active");  
$(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Both work how they should on their own, but when I try to have them work simultaneously the fade effect happens and the active class is removed from the current one when you click on another tab, but the tab which was clicked doesn't get the active class. Any idea what causes this? If it's something really easy and obvious, I apologise.

Oh, and here's my css:

```
#menu { padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    height: 25px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    position:relative;
}

#menu a{
    color:white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu a.active {
    color:black;
    background:#FCEA77;
}
```

and my HTML:

```
       <div id="menu">
        <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#info">Info</a>
        <a href="#team">Team</a>
        <a href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
        </div>
```

Thank you SO MUCH in advance!

Comment: see something different between you **backgroundColor** and your **'opacity'** keywords? (quotes?)

Comment: Well, yes, now that you say it... but it doesn't really change anything if I have them on both or not at all. Should it?

Comment: take them out of your keywords, but keep them in the values. like: backgroundColor: 'red',opacity:'0.3'

Comment: I think I accidentally deleted a comment that asked about what exactly I want to do: Basically I just want a nice hover effect, but when I use that my code for the active class switching doesn't work, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove all the single quotes from the properties in the animate
2. Use `.on('mouseenter', ...)` and `.on('mouseleave', ...)` instead of `.hover(...)`, otherwise only the elements that aren't active on document ready will be targeted
3. Put a `$(this).trigger('mouseleave');` in the `click` callback

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qcSsm/)

Comment: Oh, well this just works perfectly! Thank you so much, that's 200% what I wanted! :D

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PaJS6/11/) what you wanted?

The problem I saw was that `.animate` was adding styles directly to the `<a href>` tag, which were overriding any styles from the `.active` class according to normal CSS rules.

The simplest solution was to add `!important` to the `active` class styles:

```
#menu a.active {
    color: black !important;
    background: #FCEA77 !important;
}​
```

Comment: Yes! It works! Exactly like that, thank you so so so much! :D If I may be so bold to ask this as well: Is it possible to code that the tab that was changed to active when you click on it, won't fade out when you hover over it? It's not horribly important, but I thought I might ask.

Comment: Sure, just add `opacity: 1.0 !important;` to the `active` class: http://jsfiddle.net/PaJS6/12/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $('#menu a').hover(function(){
       if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).stop().animate({'backgroundColor': '#FCEA77', 'opacity': '0.3'}, 'slow');
            }, function() {
              $(this).stop().animate({'backgroundColor': '#000000', 'color':'#ffffff', 'opacity':     '1'}, 'slow');
        }
     }
```

and you can check this example too [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PaJS6/8/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that doesn't really work. If the class of a tab is active it _shouldn't_ be animated, that's why I put the .not in. I just want the active class to switch to the tab that was clicked, but it doesn't do that when I use the .animate, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem now. Opacity does not need the quotes at all, while other CSS rules do need it. So it is:

```
$('#menu a').not('.active').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#FCEA77', opacity: 0.3}, 'slow');
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#000000', color:'#ffffff', opacity: 1}, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That's good to know, but it doesn't really hep my problem. The hover animate still works nicely, but the active class won't switch when you click a tab...